# Problems with yield in Python | Using helper functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

Given a string with many words, I want to reverse the order of the words. If the input is `Thanks for all the fish` the output should be `fish the all for Thanks`.

I'm trying to solve this using **generators**, to avoid creating a new list.
I came up with the following solution:

```
from itertools import islice

def foo(s, begin, end):
    for elem in islice(s, begin, end):
        yield elem

def baz(s):
    i = len(s)
    j = len(s)

    while True:
        i -= 1
        if i == -1:
            foo(s, i+1, j)
            break
        if s[i] == ' ':
            foo(s, i+1, j)
            yield ' '
            j = i


s = "Thanks for all the fish"
g = baz(s)
for x in g: print(x, end='')
```

However, the output of this code is `"    "` (a string with only the spaces).

On the other hand, if I directly `print` the elements instead of yielding them, it works:

```
from itertools import islice

def foo(s, begin, end):
    for elem in islice(s, begin, end):
        print(elem, end='')

def baz(s):
    i = len(s)
    j = len(s)

    while True:
        i -= 1
        if i == -1:
            foo(s, i+1, j)
            break
        if s[i] == ' ':
            foo(s, i+1, j)
            print(' ', end='')
            j = i


s = "Thanks for all the fish"
g = baz(s)
```

This works and have as output `fish the all for Thanks`. But I do not want to just be able to print it, I want to have a correct generator.

Finally, I discovered that if avoid the calls to `foo` it also works:

```
from itertools import islice

def baz(s):
    i = len(s)
    j = len(s)

    while True:
        i -= 1
        if i == -1:
            for elem in islice(s, i+1, j):
                yield elem
            break
        if s[i] == ' ':
            for elem in islice(s, i+1, j):
                yield elem
            yield ' '
            j = i


s = "Thanks for all the fish"
g = baz(s)
for x in g: print(x, end='')
```

The output of this is `fish the all for Thanks`. 
This version gives me what I want (a correct generator), but I'm repeating code inside its function.

I red the stack exchange thread about what yield does, but I might have understood it wrong.
What I understood is that a generator will run until it finds the next yield statement (or the function ends).
This problem makes me think this is not exactly how it works, but apart from that I'm clueless.

**How can I solve this using helper functions like in the first code snippet?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `yield from foo(...)` (see also [PEP-380 on "Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)) or `for whatever in foo(...): yield whatever` to successivly `yield` the elements from a generator:

```
def baz(s):
    i = len(s)
    j = len(s)

    while True:
        i -= 1
        if i == -1:
            yield from foo(s, i+1, j)    # yield from syntax
            break
        if s[i] == ' ':
            for item in foo(s, i+1, j):  # for-loop over generator
                yield item
            yield ' '
            j = i
```

But, as @trentcl noted in the comments, in your case you don't need the `foo`-helper function because it basically does what `islice` does too. So you could simply replace `foo` with `islice`:

```
def baz(s):
    i = len(s)
    j = len(s)

    while True:
        i -= 1
        if i == -1:
            yield from islice(s, i+1, j)    # yield from syntax
            break
        if s[i] == ' ':
            for item in islice(s, i+1, j):  # for-loop over generator
                yield item
            yield ' '
            j = i
```

Comment: In fact, `foo` is a no-op; you can just `yield from islice(s, i+1, j)`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @trentcl What do you mean by `foo` is a `no-op`?

Comment: @FranciscoFigari You don't need the `foo` function. Based on the comment I added the second example, where I used `islice` directly without `foo`.

Comment: @Mseifert  I mean what's the meaning of "no-op". It means "unnecessary code"?

Comment: @FranciscoFigari A "no-op" or [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) is something (a command, line of code, instruction, etc.) that does nothing. I was using the term loosely, since strictly speaking, `foo` does something: it calls `islice`. It just doesn't add any value to calling `islice` directly